# Parsing json using jackson throws JsonMappingException

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm parsing the json below and can't get it right. It says User out of START_ARRAY token.

```
{
  "code": "true",
  "response": [
    {
      "strId": "lorem123",
      "intIdx": "176",
      "strName": "lorem",
      "strAddr": "565 lorem ipsum dolor",
      "strMobile": "010-5882-7979",
      "strBirth": "1948-01-30",
      "intExperience": "4",
      "strJob": "",
      "strJob1": "sample job1",
      "strJob2": "sample job2",
      "strJob3": "sample job3",
      "strFile": "",
      "isForeigner": "Y",
      "strEmailId": "loremid",
      "strEmailSv": "google.com",
      "strGender": "M",
      "isCarSupport": "Y"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm mapping it using this code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Response  response = mapper.readValue(url, Response.class);
return response.getUser();
```

My Response class looks like this:

```
public class Response {
    @JsonProperty("code")
    public boolean isOkay;
    @JsonProperty("response")
    public List<User> user;
//getters and setters
}
```

and my User class looks like this:

```
public class User {
    @JsonProperty("strId")
    public String id;
    @JsonProperty("intIdx")
    public int index;
    @JsonProperty("strName")
    public String name;
//... other fields
//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Please provide self-contained example demonstrating the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, if i set

```
public List<User> user;
```

to

```
public User[] user;
```

it works well..

Comment: Strange, that shouldn't make a difference. I was testing with Jackson 2.2.3. What version are you using?